# Undefined attribute in jade template engine

Tags: node.js, undefined, pug

I'm simply trying to display a value in an input field with Jade (0.20.3) and Express (2.5.8):

```
input(name='username', type='text', id="username", value=username)
```

It is quite simple, but this throws an error when the value is undefined:

```
username is not defined
```

However, the documentation indicates:

```
When a value is undefined or null the attribute is not added, so this is fine, it will not compile 'something="null"'.
```

Is there something that I would have done wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: use `locals.someVar` if you're not sure that `someVar` exists.

Longer Answer:

I think that Brandon's initial answer and last comment are correct (though the `#{...}` syntax isn't needed), but to elaborate a bit: There's a difference between passing in an a variable (technically, an object property) with a value of `undefined`, and not passing that variable at all.

Because Jade transforms your template into JS source and `eval`s it (in the context of a `with` block), you have to make sure that you're not referring to any variables that haven't been passed in, or they'll be .  [This blog post](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/) has some background on undefined vs undeclared variables and `ReferenceError`.

Your Jade template should work correctly if you do one of these things:

```
// ok, even if req.session.username is not defined
res.render('index', { username: req.session.username })

// ditto
res.local('username', req.session.username);
res.render('index')
```

But these won't work:

```
res.locals(req.session) //if no username property exists
res.render('index', { /* no username */ } )
```

If it's not practical to manually pass in each parameter you might want to refer to, you can refer to the variable in your template as properties on the `locals` object (e.g. `locals.username`)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure you're passing username into the Jade template. Example:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title:'APP NAME', username: req.session.username });
});
```

Also, you would call it like this in the Jade template: `#{username}`

Comment: Well, the thing is that it's a login page, so the username can be undefined (basically when the user first opens the page). Do I have to set a null value to the variable?

Comment: No, not at all. You're just calling the variable the wrong way. Try this: `input(name='username', type='text', id="username", value="#{username)")`

Comment: Hmmmm, just the same, `input(name='username', type='text', id="username", value="#{username}")` throws an undefined "username" error. (Thanks for the help by the way)

Comment: Are you passing the variable to the login page? If that's not happening it will throw an error. That's the only reason why it would